# How to omit/ignore column of super mapped class in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Super mapped class is declared as

```
public class Auditable extends AbstractAuditable<User, Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATUS__ID", nullable = false)
    private Status status;
```

child class extend auditable class but Status table does not contain column name as status__id

```
public class Status extends Auditable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 50, unique=true)
private String name;
```

Is there any way to omit inherited status__id column only particular in one child class. I do not want to make it transient in super mapped class as some other subclass are using it.

I have already tried @AttributeOverride and @Transient but no success. 
Note:: By default the access type is defined on field

```
@Transient
private Status status;  

@Transient
public Status getStatus() {
    return super.getStatus();
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    super.setStatus(status);
}
```

Comment: Please edit question and be more specific.

Comment: ould you explain relationss beetween status and Auditable? Is Auditable has many status or is Auditable "is a" Status? thanks.

Comment: Auditable class content basic information in order to track the changes. Status class and other entity classes extend auditable class and inherit all properties. I want to omit one property (as mention status__id column) in status class because status table does not have status__id column.